# Why does this Twig code not perform math operations as expected?

Tags: webforms

I have a registration form set up for athletes; I'm a volunteer coach.  The form contains 5 slots to register up to 5 children at a time.  There's also a donation field. Everything works fine unless the donation value goes over 999. I tried to use `number_format` in every way possible to grab the donation value and format it properly, but it still keeps adding a 1 when the number is higher than 1000.

> [image: screenshot]

This is the Twig code I am using.

```
{% apply spaceless %}
  {% set dv = (data.donation_value)|number_format(2)%}
  {% set cart_total = (data.child_registration_01_add)|number_format(0) + (data.child_registration_02_add)|number_format(0) + (data.child_registration_03_add)|number_format(0) + (data.child_registration_04_add)|number_format(0) + (data.child_registration_05_add)|number_format(0) %}

  {% set cart_1 = (data.child_registration_01_one)|number_format(2) + (dv)|number_format(2) %}

  {% set cart_2 = (data.child_registration_01_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_02_one)|number_format(2) + (dv)|number_format(2) %}

  {% set cart_3 = (data.child_registration_01_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_02_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_03_one)|number_format(2) + (dv)|number_format(2) %}

  {% set cart_4 = (data.child_registration_01_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_02_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_03_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_04_one)|number_format(2) + (dv)|number_format(2) %}

  {% set cart_5 = (data.child_registration_01_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_02_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_03_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_04_one)|number_format(2) + (data.child_registration_05_one)|number_format(2) + (dv)|number_format(2) %}

  {% if (cart_total)|number_format(0) == "1" %}
    {{ (cart_1)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
  {% elseif (cart_total)|number_format(0) == "2" %}
    {{ (cart_2)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
  {% elseif (cart_total)|number_format(0) == "3" %}
    {{ (cart_3)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
  {% elseif (cart_total)|number_format(0) == "4" %}
    {{ (cart_4)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
  {% elseif (cart_total)|number_format(0) == "5" %}
    {{ (cart_5)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
  {% else %}
    <p> 0.00 </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endapply %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It seems a rather complicate code to just sum all the values in the *Reg Fee* column and then add the value in the donation field. 1150 is the sum of the *Reg Fee* values; adding 1000 would give 2150. It seems that instead of adding 1000, the code is adding 1.

Comment: Did you try `number_format(2, '.', '')`?

Comment: @cilefen Yes, I've been trying to leverage number_format arguments. TWIG states that number_format defaults are (0, '.', ',').  So my last iteration I ended up removing the second and third arguements, using just the first.  No change.  Thanks

Comment: You did not really answer my question. Did you try precisely that?

Comment: Sorry @cilefen. Yes, I did go back and try precisely your recommendation.

Comment: It worked! @cilefen   I just had time to go back and test exactly your set of arguments everywhere and yes it worked!  **So happy** Thank you so so much!  

Final question, how might I add this to the Drupal Webform documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Use `number_format(2, '.', '')` to remove commas so you can perform math operations.